# Unbelievable 10x speed up in sklearn fitting using list subset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I made a reproducible example of what I really want to do, the problem is of the same dimension.

Can anyone explain to me these timing differences, where all I change in the fitting stage is that instead of `X[:,:]` (where the amount of variables are 504) I use `X[:,range(0,504)]`?

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
y = np.random.normal(0,1,15000)
X = np.random.normal(0,1,15000*504)
X = np.reshape(X, (15000, 504))

Z = X.copy()
Z = X[:, range(0,504)]
np.allclose(Z,X)
# True

linear_model.Ridge(alpha=100).fit(X,y)
# Timing: 54.45 seconds

linear_model.Ridge(alpha=100).fit(Z,y)
# Timing: 5.89 seconds

np.allclose(Z,X)
# True
```

How is it that by selecting a range of variables here (all of them) speeds up by almost a factor of 10? When I use `Z = X[:, :]`, the timing is also around 54 seconds.

So what is so magical about choosing a range this way?

As per DSM's request:

```
OS: Ubuntu 13.04
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.14.1'
>>> np.__version__
'1.7.0'

>>> X.__array_interface__ 
{'data': (139670867165200, False), 'shape': (15000, 504), 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
      'version': 3, 'strides': None, 'typestr': '<f8'}
>>> Z.__array_interface__ 
{'data': (139670746202128, False), 'shape': (15000, 504), 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
      'version': 3, 'strides': (8, 120000), 'typestr': '<f8'}
>>> y.__array_interface__ 
{'data': (23622352, False), 'shape': (15000,), 'descr': [('', '<f8')], 'version': 
      3, 'strides': None, 'typestr': '<f8'}
```

Comment: What is `XX`?  was it supposed to be `X`?  (line 3)

Comment: @mgilson Yes, sorry, I had to change the name in my own code to `XX` in order not to overwrite `X`'s values. I figured renaming here would be nicer.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it might make the code more clear for people who know enough about sklearn -- Rather than your `sum(sum(...))` you could use `np.all(Z == X)`

Comment: On my system, your two cases have identical timings.  Also, you could use numpy a bit more fluently :)  Use `Z = X.copy()`, `X.reshape(...)`, and `np.allclose(Z, X)`.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to ubuntu?

Comment: Also, doing `Z = X[:, range(0,504)]` will make a copy (you're using a list for "fancy" indexing), while `Z = X[:, :504]` will be identical, but won't make a copy.  However, making the copy is probably where your timing differences are coming from... Is one of your input arrays a memmapped array, by chance?

Comment: @JoeKington To what timing is it closer? I'm using single 2.3 ghz core i5 core.

Comment: @Dualinity - They both run in <1 sec.  I'm guessing that one of your input arrays is either a memmapped array, a pyhdf array, or something similar.  Therefore, making a copy loads the array into memory and results in a faster calculation.

Comment: Is anyone able to reproduce this yet?

Comment: @JoeKington What you see is what you get, this is the code that I run on a new interpreter to get the result. Could any of the things you describe have happened this way?

Comment: @JoeKington I also believe that using `X.copy()` would create a shallow and not a deep copy?

Comment: I have a slower machine than JK, it seems -- both take ~1.25 s for me, with numpy 1.9.0.dev-99ee78a and sklearn 0.15-git.  What do `X.__array_interface__` and `Y.__array_interface__` return?  Could be some unfortunate strides quirk.

Comment: @DSM Added information. It appears to be the strides thing?

Comment: @Dualinity - No, `x.copy()` will make a deep copy, if `x` is a numpy array.

Comment: @JoeKington Do you have a reference? I can only find `.copy()` returning a shallow copy, e.g. in case of a dict http://effbot.org/pyref/dict.copy.htm, and also the copy module's copy.copy is listed as shallow? I'd be happy with such a shortcut.

Comment: @Dualinity - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html (It doesn't explictly say it, but a "copy" in numpy terms is a deep copy. Views are basically shallow copies in numpy terms.) Keep in mind that I'm referring to numpy arrays and numpy arrays only.  As you've already noticed, the `copy` method for other things may return a "shallow" copy.  If you'd like to verify it yourself, try: `x = np.ones(3); y = x.copy(); x[0] = 100; print x; print y`. Compare that to `x = np.ones(3); y = x[:]; x[0] = 100; print x; print y`.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks for clearing that up to me, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: @DSM If you can provide a useful answer to why this is happening, I will accept it...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this perf discrepancy on my box with the dev version of numpy. Have you linked it against ATLAS or MKL? `from numpy.distutils.system_info import get_info; print(get_info('lapack_opt'))`.

Answer (score 2):

On my box I get:

```
>>> X.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  ...
>>> Z.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  ...
```

This means that the memory copy induced by the column-based fancy indexing has an impact on the internal memory layout of the Z array. You could also try with:

```
>>> Z2 = np.asfortranarray(X)
```

Some numpy routines might not pass the right flags to BLAS / LAPACK routines to optimize for the the C-contiguous memory layout. I am running the dev version of numpy and I cannot observe any perf discrepancy. The problem might have been fixed since the release of 1.7.0.